# How to use 'when it comes to'

Tags: sentence-construction

We can bring up the topic of anything using 'when It comes to 'sentence pattern. So here's a sentence.

When it comes to where I study,

But, the problem I'm facing is that I have no idea what exactly I should talk about where I study. I think the following are possible, but I don't know if they are:

> 1. the place that I prefer to study at; at a coffee shop or at home.
> 2. How silent it is to focus on.
> 3. How close it is from my home.

So I'd like to know how I can choose the topic so that the whole story makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What sort of things you may talk about is not determined by the phrase itself but by the context in which it occurs.

*When it comes to X* introduces *X* into the conversation, not as an entirely new topic but as a new 'subtopic'. It signals to your listener that what you will have to say about *X* is related to what you were discussing previously, but contrasts in some way with what has been said already. For instance:

> I like to have a lot of people and noise around me; I spend most of my free time at bars and ballgames. But **when it comes to where I study**, I need quiet, and I usually go to a coffee shop.
>
> For shopping or entertainment or visiting friends I'll go anywhere. I take the bus, and  I don't mind long rides, because I can meet new people and have interesting conversations. **When it comes to where I study**, though, I pick some place close to home where I can walk, because I want to be alone and focus my mind on what I'll be working on when I get there.

Answer (score 1):

Your No.1 point would work with a bit of tweaking:

> When it comes to where I study, I prefer to study at a coffee shop.

Or you could use the second and third points like this:

> When it comes to where I study, it depends on how close it is from my home.
>
> When it comes to where I study, it depends on how silent it is so that I can focus.

You can even start switching things around:

> When it comes to where I study, it needs to be a silent place so that I can focus.

I hope you can start to recognise the general structure.

You can also use the phrase "With regards to":

> With regards to where I study, I like to study in a place where it is quiet.

There are many different ways that you can form these sentences, you just need to find the level of formality that you want, or you might be thinking about the atmosphere you might convey.